# jQueryで'mousewheel'イベントが複数呼ばれるのを中止するにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: javascript, jquery

◎マウスホイールが一度回された時に、一度だけ処理し、
再度回すとまた処理するというものを作りたいです。

「jquery.mousewheel.js」というプラグインを使っています。

下のコードだと、大きくホイールを回すと、複数回'mousewheel'イベントが呼ばれてしまいます。

mousewheelイベントが発生した直後に

```
.off("mousewheel")
```

としているのですが、mousewheelイベント自体の発生を止めるものではないのですかね。

◎なぜtrue／falseのフラグたと処理をスルーできないのかの理由も教えていただけますと幸いです。

```js
$(function(){

 var timer;
 var index = 0;
 var delay = 1000; //次のスクロールを許容する時間
 var boxes = $('.box');

 //ホイールイベントを検知
 $(document).on('mousewheel', function(eo, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
  console.log('mousewheel');
  count(eo, delta)
 });

 //関数の定義
 function count(eo, delta){
  if (delta === -1){
    $(document).off("mousewheel")//ホイールの検知を中止
    console.log('下');
    index = index + 1
    if (index >= boxes.length-1) {
     index = boxes.length-1
    }
    changeBox(index);
    timer = setInterval(allowCount, delay);
  }

  if (delta === 1) {
    $(document).off("mousewheel")//ホイールの検知を中止
    console.log('上');
    index = index - 1
    if (index < 0) {
     index = 0
    }
    changeBox(index);
    timer = setInterval(allowCount, delay);
  }

  function allowCount() {
   console.log('go!');

   //ホイールを検知の再登録
   $(document).on("mousewheel",function(eo, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
    console.log('mousewheel');
    count(eo, delta)
   })
   clearInterval(timer)
  }
 }

 function changeBox(index) {
  var cur = $('.effect');
  cur.removeClass('effect');
  boxes.eq(index).addClass('effect');
 }
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

html,body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}


.container{
 height: 100%;
 display:grid;
 grid-auto-rows: 50px;
 grid-template-columns: 80%;
 justify-content: center;
 grid-gap: 5px;
}

.box{
 background: pink;
}

.effect{
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

イベントの間隔で判断すると良いかも

```
    var timer;
    var index = 0;
    var interval = 100;
    var boxes = $('.box');
    var last_time = 0;

    //ホイールイベントを検知
    $(document).on('mousewheel', function(eo, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
        console.log('mousewheel');
            var now = new Date().getTime();
        if (now - last_time > interval){
                count(eo, delta)
        }
        last_time = now;
    });
```

Comment: うまくいきました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: なぜon／offメソッドの方だうまくいかないのでしょうか？

Comment: １，JavaScriptはシングルスレッドで動き、キューに登録された関数が順番にひとつずつ実行する。
２，イベント（割り込み処理）が起きると、先ずキューに処理を登録します。（取りあえず、登録するだけで直ぐに元のスレッドへ戻ります。）
３，スレッドが動いていなければ、すぐに実行されます。スレッドが動いているなら（他の処理中なら）、スレッドが完了するか中断されるまで実行が保留され
４、次に実行する処理はキューから決めます。
以上から、先に複数のイベント処理がキューに登録されます。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます！勉強させていただきます！もし参考のサイトなどあれば、お教えいただけますと嬉しいです。

Answer (score 2):

ホイールは回るものなので「一度だけ動かす」という考え方自体がおかしいのです。おそらくマウスホイールが一定角度で段階的に(カクカクと)回るタイプのマウスをお使いなのでしょうが、無段階に周り続けるホイールを持つマウスも存在しています。またタッチパッドのスクロールのようなものも無段階になっているかと思います。そのためそのようなUIを作成することは個人的にあまり推奨しません。

しかしどうしてもやりたいのであれば、イベントを処理した時の時刻を記録しておいて次に発生したイベントが時の現在時間と比較して一定期間内ならばイベントを無視して処理をしないようにすればいいのではないでしょうか？

追記)
以下のようにしてもうまくいかないということでしょうか？

```
$(function(){

    var timer;
    var index = 0;
    var delay = 1000; //次のスクロールを許容する時間
    var last_time = 0;
    var boxes = $('.box');

    //ホイールイベントを検知
    $(document).on('mousewheel', function(eo, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
        console.log('mousewheel');
        var now = new Date().getTime()
        if (now - last_time >= delay) {
             last_time = now;
            count(eo, delta)
        }
    });

    //関数の定義
    function count(eo, delta){
        console.log('処理するよ');
        if (delta === -1){
                console.log('下');
                index = index + 1
                if (index >= boxes.length-1) {
                    index = boxes.length-1
                }
                changeBox(index);
        }

        if (delta === 1) {
                console.log('上');
                index = index - 1
                if (index < 0) {
                    index = 0
                }
                changeBox(index);
        }
    }

    function changeBox(index) {
        console.log('changeBox() : index => ' + index);
        var cur = $('.effect');
        cur.removeClass('effect');
        boxes.eq(index).addClass('effect');
    }
});
```

Comment: はじめてイベントが発生した時にフラグとして設定した変数、例えばallowProcess = falseにして、setTimeoutで1秒後にallowProcess = trueとなる処理を登録し、falseの間は、mouseWheelされた時の処理をしないという形で書いていたのですが、それでもmouseWheelのイベントは重複して登録されてしまうようで、連続して処理が行われてしまいます。そのためmousewheelイベント自体の受信や発生を止めて、一定時間後に再開するということはできないのかという趣旨で質問させていただきました。

Comment: 今回は通常のマウスホイールの使い方とは違う形の使い方をしています。「マウスホイールを回す動作が終わった時」というイベントが取得できたらそのタイミングで処理すれば良いかと思って調べたのですが、そういうイベントは見つからず、質問させていただきました。

Comment: この記事の内容で’ホイールストップ’の取得ができるかもしれません。http://www.risewill.co.jp/blog/archives/2618

Comment: 仮に、「mousewheelイベント自体の発生を止める」ことができたとしても、上のコードで２回動作してしまうということはイベントハンドラが実行される前に複数のイベントが発生してキューに登録されているので、手遅れですよね。もっと単純に２回目のイベントハンドラの呼び出しで何もしないようにしましょうという話ですが…

Comment: コードありがとうございます！試してみます！